# NaN value when getHours()

Tags: javascript, datetime, nan

I m trying to get the hours and minutes from a date but I get the NaN value. What's wrong here?

```
var date= cars.getAttribute("myLastDate");
var hour= date.getHours();
alert (hour);
```

Thank you in advanced.

Best regards.

Comment: you need to convert your date variable to datetime. you can post your html code part

Comment: `getAttribute` (on an element) should return a string, which has no `getHours` function.  We need more context.

Comment: I dont have html code, it is all javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var date= cars.getAttribute("myLastDate");
var d = new Date(date);
var n = d.getHours();
```

Comment: can you give us what the cars.getAttribute('myLastDate') contains ? do a console.log if u want .

Comment: this date is what I m trying to get: 27/11/2012 0:15:51

Comment: the problem is the order of the date. If i type the month before the day it works var d = new Date("11/27/2012 0:15:51"); so your solution is good. Now i need to change the order....